# Is there a benefit to having both truesight and darkvision?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, vision-and-light

The Avatar of Death (as summoned by the *skull* card in a [*deck of many things*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/deck-of-many-things)) has both truesight and darkvision to a range of 60ft. The darkvision seems redundant, because truesight already lets you see through *all* darkness as if it were normal lighting. Is there any benefit to having both abilities?

Comment: Hi @QPaul - I've rephrased your question slightly so that it asks directly about the mechanical implications of the rules, rather than specifically why a certain creature was written a certain way. The latter question is likely to get closed as a designer-reasons query (which we've decided isn't a good fit for the site, as such questions tend to produce a lot of unsupported speculation), but we can at least analyse the rules to see if there is a meaningful benefit to having both.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## The Avatar of Death probably not, a PC possibly

The Avatar of Death would likely always use truesight, as darkvision has less benefits.

If a PC was granted truesight and darkvision of 60 feet a PC would likely always use truesight up to the 60 foot range. A mechanical benefit to having darkvision would be the possible ability to increase the range of the darkvision beyond 60 feet. Using class features such as the Ranger Gloom Stalker’s **Umbral Sight**, the range for darkvision would be extended to 90 feet.